# How to implement HTTP 1.1 POST using Openssl in C

Tags: c, openssl

How to do HTTP 1.1 post using the Openssl library consume the response in C language without using libcurl library.

Call https://example.com with HTTP 1.1 Post and consume the response.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, there's no HTTP 1.2 protocol. Also, you want to use `libcurl` to achieve that.

Comment: @sturcotte06 updated the question it is HTTP 1.2 and without using libcurl library

Comment: Then follow this tutorial: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client
You'll probably want to use `libcurl` afterwards.